# How to remove GRUB which is installed in another partition (except MBR) during Dual Boot setup

Tags: linux, bash, windows, dual-boot, grub

I installed Kali Linux with Win10 (primary os) in a dual boot setup (I used bootable DVD for OS installing). During boot I wanted Win10 Boot menu rather than GRUB. I followed a tutorial to do this available in Youtube using EasyBCD.
[I followed this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrv75yq0Rdo)

**Yesterday:** My HDD had 4 partitions which were correspondingly: MBR(Boot partition/system I guess), C: drive(Win10 installed), D: drive(my user data), unallocated_space(that I used it to install Linux).
Now during kali linux setup, I selected the unallocated space for Setup(/root,/home,/var,/tmp,/swap) and I selected my third partition(not MBR) of only HDD for GRUB installing (using /dev/sda3) as instructions shown. The installation was successful and everything went according to that tutorial. After reboot, the pc booted into win10 and I launched EasyBCD to configure the boot menu. Then I rebooted and launched Kali linux from the boot menu. Everything was a success and worked accordingly.
**Today:** For some issues, I deleted the kali linux partitions from Win10 disk manager and removed Kali linux option from the boot menu using EasyBCD. When I tried to reinstall Kali Linux from the bootable DVD, it showed a GRUB Bash rather than a Installation Window.
**My Q:** Why It's showing the GRUB Bash rather than Installation Window? Is it happening because of the previous GRUB setup that i made? How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think that GRUB Bash has anything to do with the previous installation , rather it might be a sign of faulty bootable DVD .

Comment: No, the dvd is working properly. I checked the dvd in another laptop. It's working fine. Not an issue with the dvd 

Comment: Did you mix UEFI & BIOS installs? You always want to install in same boot mode as Windows. And if Windows pre-installed, and system Windows 8 or later it will be UEFI. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair